# CORS and Cookies working together with PHP headers and jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to use php headers to accept cookies and various types of ajax requests to my api.  Also the request can come from any server, so I can't whitelist them.  I'd like to use

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

but this blocks cookies.  Is there a way around this?

Here's the setup for the ajax calls with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    },
    url: "https://myothersite.com/login_submit.php"...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set or read cookies on cross origin resource sharing requests through JavaScript. Cookies respect the browser's same origin policy.